# CREATE UNIQUE in neo4j produces duplicate nodes

Tags: neo4j

According to the [neo4j documentation](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-create-unique.html):

> CREATE UNIQUE is in the middle of MATCH and CREATE — it will match
>   what it can, and create what is missing. CREATE UNIQUE will always
>   make the least change possible to the graph — if it can use parts of
>   the existing graph, it will.

This sounds great, but `CREATE UNIQUE` doesn't seem to follow the 'least possible change' rule. e.g., here is some Cypher to create two people:

```
CREATE (n:Person {name: 'Alice'})

CREATE (n:Person {name: 'Bob'})

CREATE INDEX ON :Person(name)
```

and here's two `CREATE UNIQUE` statements, to create a relationship between those people. Since both people already exist in the graph, only the relationships should be newly created:

```
MATCH (a:Person {name: 'Alice'}) 
CREATE UNIQUE (a)-[:knows]->(b:Person {name: 'Bob'}) 
RETURN a

MATCH (a:Person {name: 'Alice'}) 
CREATE UNIQUE (a)<-[:knows]-(b:Person {name: 'Bob'}) 
RETURN a
```

After this, the graph should look like

```
(Alice)<---KNOWS--->(Bob).
```

But when you run a MATCH query:

```
MATCH (a:Person) 
RETURN a
```

it seems that the graph now looks like

```
(Bob)   

(Bob)--KNOWS-->(Alice)--KNOWS-->(Bob);
```

two extra Bobs have been created.

I looked a bit through the other Cypher commands, but none of them seem intended for this use case: create a link between existing node A and existing node B if B exists, and otherwise create a link between existing node A and a newly created node B. How can this problem best be solved within the Cypher framework?

Comment: Note that `CREATE UNIQUE` [has been deprecated](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/create-unique/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query should do what you want (if you always want to end up with a single `knows` relationship between the 2 nodes):

```
MATCH (a:Person {name: 'Alice'})
MERGE (b:Person {name: 'Bob'})
MERGE (a)-[:knows]->(b)
RETURN a;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can do it with CREATE UNIQUE

```
MATCH (a:Person {name: 'Alice'}), (b:Person {name:'Bob'}) 
CREATE UNIQUE (a)-[:knows]->(b), (b)-[:knows]->(a)
```

You need 2 match clauses otherwise you are always creating the node in the CREATE UNIQUE statement, not matching existing nodes.